# Is this a form of plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, research-misconduct, consulting

Recently, I had an author contact me regarding naming me as a consultant on a project of theirs, rather than co-author, if I was to contribute. No fee was discussed at all.

Was it a form of plagiarism to avoid naming me as "author"?

For some reason, they seemingly did not want to cite my published research (which they have ended up doing anyway since I declined the invitation).

Does anyone please have an opinion as to why they tried to avoid the citation in the first place?

Comment: Whatever it is, it isn't plagiarism. Without a lot more information we can't begin to guess what it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From what I could gather, the intention was to report results from an existing study I wrote, change them slightly to incorporate different literature and then name themselves as an author, and myself, as a consultant.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the group that contacted you plan to represent your work as their own, it is not plagiarism.  Even if they don't do that, there may still be ethical issues that aren't plagiarism.

You have the right to ask, before you agree to anything, how your work will be credited in publication.  If you don't like the answer they give you, then request modification, or back out of doing the work.  Before you start, you should also understand very clearly if there will be any compensation, monetary or otherwise, in exchange for the work.

My suspicion is that the want to offer you an "acknowledgement" in the papers that result.  You should ask about the parameters of the whole project, and if you think your part of it would merit authorship, say so.

Get *all of this* hashed out *before you make any commitment*.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I attempted to get as much detail as possible but they simply stopped replying which kind of told me everything I needed to know.